# LINQ to Entities query to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datagridview, datatable

I need to store the data returned from this LINQ to Entities query (below) into a DataTable so that I can use it as data source to a DataGridView, how can I do that?

In this case I'm using LINQ to Entities to query against an Entity Framework conceptual model, so `db` is a class that inherits from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.

```
using (TccContext db = new TccContext())
{
    var query = from vendedor in db.Vendedores.AsEnumerable()
                where vendedor.codigo == Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPesquisa.Text)
                select vendedor;
    // I'd like to do something like DataTable dt = query;
}
```

I've tried to do this (below), but it throws an exception during execution [1].

```
using (TccContext db = new TccContext())
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> query = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)(from vendedor in db.Vendedores.AsEnumerable()
                                                        where vendedor.codigo == Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPesquisa.Text)
                                                        select vendedor);

    using (DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>())
    {
        this.dataGridViewProcura.Rows.Add(
            dt.Rows[0][0],  // Código
            dt.Rows[0][1],  // Nome
            dt.Rows[0][2]); // Venda Mensal
    }
}
```

[1]: Exception: `InvalidCastException`

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Projeto_TCC.Models.Vendedor]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is one important thing here, you are casting your Linq query to (`IEnumerable<DataRow>`) when you are selecting the `vendedor`, so I assume that vendedor is an instance of `Vendedor`, so your query will return an `IEnumerable<Vendedor>`

That should solve your problem, but also, can you try using the generated DataTable as the DataSource for your DataGridView? It would be something like this:

```
var query = (from vendedor in db.Vendedores.AsEnumerable()
                   where vendedor.codigo == Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPesquisa.Text)
                   select vendedor);
var dt = query.CopyToDataTable<Vendedor>();
this.dataGridViewProcura.DataSource = dt;
```

Hope I can help!

**EDIT**

As a side (and very personal) note, you could try using lambdas on your select, they look prettier :)

```
var pesquisa = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPesquisa.Text);
var query = db.Vendedores.Where(vendedor => vendedor.codigo == pesquisa);

var dt = query.CopyToDataTable<Vendedor>();
this.dataGridViewProcura.DataSource = dt;
```

A lot cleaner, don't you think?

**EDIT 2**
I've just realized what you said on CopyToDataTable being for DataRow only, so last (admittedly not so clean) solution would be to mimic the logic on the helper?

```
public DataTable CopyGenericToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var result = new DataTable();

    //Build the columns
    foreach ( var prop in properties ) {
        result.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    //Fill the DataTable
    foreach( var item in items ){
        var row = result.NewRow();

        foreach ( var prop in properties ) {
            var itemValue = prop.GetValue(item, new object[] {});
            row[prop.Name] = itemValue;
        }

        result.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, **things to consider**:

- This solution **will not** work with complex properties
- Customizing the resulting table might be a bit tricky

While this might solve the issue, I don't think this is a very good approach, but it could be the start of a decent idea :)

I hope I can help this time!

Comment: The method CopyToDataTable will not be available in the `query` if I use it like that. Please note that I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: I made a typo on the last source, and as the edit says, the CopyToDataTable method should work there. btw - Did the answer helped at all?

Comment: As you can see in the same link, to gain access to the CopyToDataTable method the T type in the IEnumerable<T> must be of type DataRow, but as instead you used the class that represents the database table Vendedor I end up not having access to those extension methods that includes the CopyToDataTable.

Comment: It is not valid solution for converting to data table

Comment: @David Conde I spend a little time trying to implement your initial solution, as I believed I had stumbled upon a quick fix that I had overlooked. Unfortunately, I arrived at the same dead end as zigrid. 
I was a little frustrating to then read the comments and realize that this is not a valid option.

Comment: I have been implementing a couple of other Object "shredder" to DataTable solutions such as the one you suggest in your EDIT 2(@David Conde ), but I have discovered that can be either problematic for complex types (as mentioned) especially EntityTypes with foreign keys or very costly or both.
 I think that in many cases it is simply best to abandon the Entity types and query the DB directly which easily converts to a DataTable

Answer (score 0):

This is a the **MSDN** recommended solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx

I have Implemented it successfully
(*with minor additions to handle nullable DateTime.)
as Follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;


/// <summary>
/// Converts Entity Type to DataTable
/// </summary>
public class ObjectShredder<T>
{
    private System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] _fi;
    private System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _pi;
    private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> _ordinalMap;
    private System.Type _type;

    // ObjectShredder constructor.
    public ObjectShredder()
    {
        _type = typeof(T);
        _fi = _type.GetFields();
        _pi = _type.GetProperties();
        _ordinalMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a DataTable from a sequence of objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The sequence of objects to load into the DataTable.</param>
    /// <param name="table">The input table. The schema of the table must match that 
    /// the type T.  If the table is null, a new table is created with a schema 
    /// created from the public properties and fields of the type T.</param>
    /// <param name="options">Specifies how values from the source sequence will be applied to 
    /// existing rows in the table.</param>
    /// <returns>A DataTable created from the source sequence.</returns>
    public DataTable Shred(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
    {
        // Load the table from the scalar sequence if T is a primitive type.
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
        {
            return ShredPrimitive(source, table, options);
        }

        // Create a new table if the input table is null.
        if (table == null)
        {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        // Initialize the ordinal map and extend the table schema based on type T.
        table = ExtendTable(table, typeof(T));

        // Enumerate the source sequence and load the object values into rows.
        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (options != null)
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), (LoadOption)options);
                }
                else
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }

    public DataTable ShredPrimitive(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
    {
        // Create a new table if the input table is null.
        if (table == null)
        {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        if (!table.Columns.Contains("Value"))
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(T));
        }

        // Enumerate the source sequence and load the scalar values into rows.
        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                values[table.Columns["Value"].Ordinal] = e.Current;

                if (options != null)
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, (LoadOption)options);
                }
                else
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }

    public object[] ShredObject(DataTable table, T instance)
    {

        FieldInfo[] fi = _fi;
        PropertyInfo[] pi = _pi;

        if (instance.GetType() != typeof(T))
        {
            // If the instance is derived from T, extend the table schema
            // and get the properties and fields.
            ExtendTable(table, instance.GetType());
            fi = instance.GetType().GetFields();
            pi = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
        }

        // Add the property and field values of the instance to an array.
        Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            values[_ordinalMap[f.Name]] = f.GetValue(instance);
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)
        {
            values[_ordinalMap[p.Name]] = p.GetValue(instance, null);
        }

        // Return the property and field values of the instance.
        return values;
    }

    public DataTable ExtendTable(DataTable table, Type type)
    {
        // Extend the table schema if the input table was null or if the value 
        // in the sequence is derived from type T.            
        foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields())
        {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(f.Name))
            {
                // Add the field as a column in the table if it doesn't exist
                // already.
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(f.Name) ? table.Columns[f.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.FieldType);

                // Add the field to the ordinal map.
                _ordinalMap.Add(f.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name))
            {
                // Add the property as a column in the table if it doesn't exist already.
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns[p.Name];
                //Added Try Catch to account for Nullable Types  
                try
                {
                    dc = table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) ? table.Columns[p.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException nsEx)
                {
                    string pType = p.PropertyType.ToString();
                    dc = pType.Contains("System.DateTime") ? table.Columns.Add(p.Name, typeof(System.DateTime)) : table.Columns.Add(p.Name);
                    //dc = table.Columns.Add(p.Name); //Modified to above statment in order to accomodate Nullable date Time 
                }




                // Add the property to the ordinal map.
                _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }
}
```

}

The (big) caveat to this solution is that it is ** costly** and you have to customize it in the error handling.

Answer (score -2):

you can put

var query = from ....

this.dataGridViewProcura.DataSource = query.**tolist()**